# Why can I not to readdress pointer within an outer function in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, allocation, memory-address

I have a simple code:

```
void function1(int* A);
void function2(int* A);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    int* A = new int[4];
    // Readdressed into function1: A[0] is preserved
    A[0] = 21;
    function1(A);
    cout << "\nA[0] is: " << A[0];
    // Result A[0] = 21

    // Is not readdressed into function2: A[0] is not preserved
    A[0] = 21;
    function2(A);
    cout << "\nA[0] is: " << A[0];
    // Result A[0] = 23

    return 0;
}

void function1(int* A) {
    A = new int[4];
    A[0] = 23;
}
void function2(int* A) {
    A[0] = 23;
}
```

**Output:**

In the case of function1 output A[0] is 21

In the case of function2 output A[0] is 23

**Question:**
Why does A-pointer not get (In the first case) an address to a new allocated memory cells where A[0] is 23, and preserve an address where A[0] is 21 instead ?

Comment: Remember that arguments are passed *by value*, which means the value of the expression in the call is copied into functions local argument variable. In `function1` and `function2` the variable `A` is a local copy, and if you modify it like you do in `function1` that modification will be lost when the function returns and the life-time of the variable ends. This should be mentioned and perhaps even showcased in any decent [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), tutorial or class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you pass a reference, parameters are passed by value. Pointers are no different.

```
void function1(int* A) {
    A = new int[4];
    A[0] = 23;
}
void function2(int* A) {
    A[0] = 23;
}
```

`function1` assigns a new value to `A`. However, `A` is a local variable in `function1`. Assining `23` to the first element of that new array, does not affect the array `A` was originally pointing to.

`function2` gets `A` passed by value as well. Though, it does not attempt to modify `A`. It just uses `A` to write `23` at the adress pointed to by `A`.

---

Consider this example which is similar to your `function1`:

```
#include <iostream>


int a,b = 0;

void function1(int* p) {
    p = &b;
    *p = 42;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << a << b << "\n";
    int* ptr = &a;
    function1(ptr);
    std::cout << a << b << *ptr << "\n";
}
```

Output is

```
00 
0420
```

because after calling `function1` `ptr` in `main` still points to `a`. The `p = &b;` in `function1` only affects `p` which is local to `function1`.